# How can I use Responsive Design principles to fix this screen size issue?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

For a project of mine I decided to start using Responsive Design.  The guide I was using wasn't definitive and purely introductory so I got lost somewhere there and can't find the problem here.  If use the code below you'll render yourself a navigation menu.  It looks fine on a 13 inch screen but go to a smaller screen size by perhaps shortening the width of your browser you'll notice that the navigation menu will take over the logo's space.  How can I tweak this so that the navigation menu won't be on top of the logo and perhaps will stop before it goes over the logo?

**HTML:**

```
<header class="bar_top">
    <div class="logo_block">
        <a href="index.php">
            <img alt="Logo" src="/logo.png" class="logo">
        </a>
    </div>
    <nav class="menu_above">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu_inner"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menu_inner"><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
            <li class="menu_inner"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li class="menu_inner"><a href="#">About Company</a></li>
            <li class="menu_inner"><a href="#">Contact</a>
                <ul class="menu_layer">
                    <li class="menu_contact_is"><a class="menu_contact_inner" href="#">Menu 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu_contact_is"><a class="menu_contact_inner" href="#">Menu 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu_contact_is"><a class="menu_contact_inner" href="#">Menu 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <span class="phone_us">000-000-0000</span>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bar_top {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size:14.5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 82px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}

.logo_block {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 998;
}
.logo {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    height: 85px;
}
.menu_above {
    width: 960px;
    margin:  40px auto;
    float:right;
}
.menu_layer {
    margin-left: -40px;
}
.menu_contact_is {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
a.menu_contact_inner {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
.phone_us {
    font-size: 1.5625em;
    margin-left: 75px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the attribute margin: auto; to set elements on the center of the screen or the container, instead of using static values to position the elements

Also you can read about **flexible design** and **responsive design** to learn about.

Comment: I was using margin: 40px auto; but now I am resorting to simply defining the margin-left part since it seems I can't get it to work using what i have above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to keep the menu next to the logo on the left side of the page you should try this:

```
 .logo_block {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
  }

.menu_above {
        margin: 40px auto;
        display: inline-block;
 }
```

It's quite common to wrap the content with a div container that has a fixed with and auto margin on the sides to keep it on the center of the page.

You should also consider to revise the other **elements** on you page as you are using **unnecessary relative positioning**. ;)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  The other relative positions are neccessary for some other elements that I had conflicts with.  But I did remove the one from the .logo one.